# Postgres conditional union?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

If I have the queries:-

```
SELECT foo FROM baa where foo='value'
```

AND

```
SELECT foo FROM wobble WHERE foo='value'
```

Can I write an SQL query in postgres such that the second query does not run if the first query returns results without using a common table expression or repeating the first query?

The reason is that both queries are quite heavy, the second query is a fallback in the case that the first query does not return results.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a CTE?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that it can be done in plain SQL, but in a PL/pgSQL function it is rather straightforward, assuming that both queries return the same set of columns. Given that both queries are "heavy", the function overhead is minimal. A bonus feature is that the query plan gets cached, so successive calls will be faster. Another bonus feature is that you could make `foo` a parameter so you could query for something other than "value".

```
CREATE FUNCTION run_heavy_query()
RETURNS TABLE (foo text, ...) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT foo FROM baa WHERE foo='value';
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT foo FROM wobble WHERE foo='value';
    END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

The `STABLE` function volatility modifier lets the query planner optimize successive calls but you should not be using any `VOLATILE` function calls in your queries.

Now you can simply

```
SELECT * FROM run_heavy_query();
```